# Word Clouds using Stanford NLP libraries

Tags: d3.js, stanford-nlp

I would like to create a word cloud using D3 js and Standford NLP.
The word cloud would be grouping of words within concepts.
Like this:

[image]

Each cloud is a "concept" and the inner bubbles are "sub-concepts" with in concepts.

```
For exampleif concept is "World Economic Issues"
The Words under it would be - Oil Price, China Economy, Euro Zone Crisis, Japan debt crisis
```

I have used parts of speech tagger and sentiment analysis but have no idea how to approach creating a word cloud.

Are there libraries within Standford NLP to conceptualize words from a blurb of text?
Please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question depends in large part on what you'd like the categories to represent. I've given a few examples below; although, note that in all of these cases you're getting noisy categories:

- Topic Modeling (see http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.4/). Running this on a large corpus of text will give you a fixed number of "topics" with words associated with them. These are words that pertain to the same concept in some fuzzy way, and is maybe the closest to what you're describing. In the vanilla case, you end up with clusters of words in a fixed number of categories -- but, you don't have labels on the categories themselves. You can try Labeled LDA if you want to fix the categories beforehand (see the bottom of the page).
- Word vectors (https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/ or http://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/). These will give you a vector for every word. Now, you can calculate things like the words with the nearest cosine similarity (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity#Definition) to your topic labels. This will give you words related to the original word; formally, it will give you words that tend to appear in similar contexts in sentences as the original word.
- Stanford NLP Tools (http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml). This is a collection of standard NLP tools that you can cluster according to. These will, in general, be clusters with very specific interpretations. For example, the part of speech tagger will cluster nouns together, and verbs together, etc. The sentiment analyzer will cluster positive sentiment words together and negative words together. The named entity tagger will cluster people together, and organizations together, etc.
- Word frequency. These word clouds are usually created using word frequencies. If you have a bunch of documents in each of your topics, you can just count the number of times each word occurs in your topics and use that as your visualization. If this ends up with lots of common words at the top, you can try filtering by part-of-speech tags, or you can try taking tf-idf (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) values or something similar.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much for your thoughts @Gabor Angeli